# How to turn off window title git edit status in VSCode 1.55+

Tags: visual-studio-code

Before VSCode 1.55 it was easy to distinguish what editor window you had open as the text was white:

[image: white-active-window-text]

Now they made an update so that it's almost impossible to tell what file you have open in many themes (where the active tab bg is unchanged/subtle on active state) since it colours the title yellow regardless of whether it's active or not:

`MarginAccountContainer.tsx` is active:

[image: MarginAccountContainer.tsx is active]

`.env` is active:

[image: .env is active]

When you have 8 yellow tab titles in a row it's really confusing. Is there a way to disabled this "feature"?

Comment: The yellow color is about the GIT Lens extension that makes the modified file's header yellow.

Comment: @J.Hpour I thought so too (and tried disabling) but turns out it's a VSCode built in thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is under Settings, `Workbench > Editor > Decorations`.

[image]